# Custom dictionary parsing in Python using class

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

1. Json data I am trying to parse into a data frame or csv file.

```
{
    "reports": [
        {
            "columnHeader": {
                "dimensions": [
                    "ga:date",
                    "ga:dcmLastEventSitePlacement"
                ],
                "metricHeader": {
                    "metricHeaderEntries": [
                        {
                            "name": "ga:sessions",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ga:dcmCost",
                            "type": "CURRENCY"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "data": {
                "maximums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "2523",
                            "396.7911"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "minimums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "0",
                            "0.0"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "rowCount": 503,
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "20191023",
                            "brand"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "4",
                                    "0.0"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "20191023",
                            "brand"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "13",
                                    "0.0"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                       ],
                "totals": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "4923",
                            "7914.29571"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Code that I tried

```
class GAReportParser:
    def __init__(self, request_response):
        self.request_response = request_response
        # column_indices = {}

    def get_csv(self):
        csv_rows = [self.get_header_csv()]
        rows = self.request_response['data']['rows']
        for row in rows:
            # pprint(row['dimensions'])
            row_csv = ','.join(row['dimensions'])
            metrics = row['metrics']
            for metric in metrics:
                row_csv += ',' + ','.join(metric['values'])
            csv_rows.append(row_csv)

        return "\n".join(csv_rows)

    def get_header_csv(self):
        headers = self.request_response['columnHeader']['dimensions']
        metricHeaders = self.request_response['columnHeader'][
            'metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries']
        for metricHeader in metricHeaders:
            headers.append(metricHeader['name'])

        headers_csv = ','.join(headers)
        return headers_csv
```

3. Error I am getting

KeyError: 'columnHeader'

Can anyone please help me with the error or a simpler way to parse this file into a csv or df ? 
I am expecting the output to be

ga:date | ga:dcmLastEventSitePlacement | ga:sesssions | ga:dcmCost
2019-09-04 | brand                      | 4            |0

--edit-- 
4. CORRECT solution with help from @Sadrach Pierre

```
class GAReportParser:

    def __init__(self, request_response):
        self.request_response = request_response

    def get_csv(self):
        print("get_csv is called")
        csv_rows = [self.get_header_csv()]

        metricHeaders = self.request_response['reports']
        for metricHeader in metricHeaders:
            for row in metricHeader['data']['rows']:
                row_csv = ','.join(row['dimensions'])
                metrics = row['metrics']
                for metric in metrics:
                    row_csv += ',' + ','.join(metric['values'])
                csv_rows.append(row_csv)

       return "\n".join(csv_rows)


    def get_header_csv(self):
        headers = []
        Headers = self.request_response['reports']
        for Header in Headers:
            for items in Header['columnHeader']['dimensions']:
                headers.append(items)
            for name in Header['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries']:
                headers.append(name['name'])

        headers_csv = ','.join(headers)
        return headers_csv
```

Comment: Do you ever parse the JSON file using the JSON built-in module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: yes, you must get an error. first, you must iterate over `reports` list, then use `self.request_response['columnHeader']['dimensions']`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
def get_header_csv(self):
    headers = []
    metricHeaders = self.request_response['reports']
    for metricHeader in metricHeaders:
        for name in metricHeader['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries']:
            headers.append(name['name'])

    headers_csv = ','.join(headers)
    return headers_csv
```

Comment: awesome @Sadrach Pierre.Thanks a lot bud

Answer (score 0):

If the list contains valid `JSON` strings then you can use `json.loads()`

i.e.

```
import json
json_list = ['{"a": 1}', '{"a": 2}']

dict_list = [json.loads(d) for d in json_list]
```